# How to return json data selectively in a struts2 action class

Tags: java, json, struts2

I have several properties with getter and setter method in one action class.

Those properties do not perform the same task. Actually, they respond to different business-service requests, or they are related to different actions.

And my problem is like this:

I need to filter out the data and return only part of the properties within the property set because not all properties are necessary in a single request(action).

PS:Actually, I might have separated those actions or business logic into several classes instead of putting them into one action class. However, I think they all share the similar DAOs and services so I put them together in order to prevent redundant IOCs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Struts2-JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) allows you to exclude null properties

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="excludeNullProperties">true</param>
</result>
```

or exclude certain parameters from being serialized

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="excludeProperties">
    login.password,
    studentList.*\.sin
  </param>
</result>
```

See [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks very much, but I found another thing that I cannot understand.

Comment: If I use <param name="root"> some properties</param>, it works fine. However, if I use <param name="includeProperties"> the same set properties</param>, it does not work. Note here I included the same set of properties.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question. It will give more people a chance to answer your question and gain recognition for it.