# Struts2 Only Use Specific Variable Object for JSON Result (not all Action variables)

Tags: json, struts2

Suppose my Struts mapping returns a JSON string,

```
    <action name="retrieveJson" method="retrieveJson" class="myapp.WebServiceAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
        </result>       
    </action>
```

My Action class has multiple variables that could be "construed" as the potential result.

```
public class WebServiceAction {
   private List<PublicationRecord> publicationRecords; // getters+setters
   private List<ReviewRecord> reviewRecords; // getters+setters
   private List<CustomRecord> customRecords; // getters+setters
}
```

When I do the following, I set the particular variable that I want, but Struts2 seems to return all variables under the Action that are suitable:

```
public String retrieveJson() {
   publicationRecords = service.getPublicationRecords();
   return SUCCESS;
}
```

Is it wrong to return SUCCESS? I only want the JSON-ified variable that I set in this method. Right now, it's returning all 3 vars,

```
{
  "publicationRecords" : ..,
  "reviewRecords" : null,
  "customRecords" : null
}
```

Expected:

```
{"publicationRecords" : .. }
```

Comment: I think I found the solution, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880276/how-to-return-json-data-selectively-in-a-struts2-action-class  it's `excludeNullProperties` or `excludeProperties` by name

Comment: It's also in the plugin's documentation :/ That's often a good place to start looking for documentation. Unrelated, but why are you setting the response to `text/plain` instead of indicating it's JSON?

Comment: Thanks; I have another question that maybe you could answer that I scoured the documentation for but couldn't find a clean answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51974251/struts2-2-3-34-rename-some-json-fields-in-object-output  How to customize the resulting JSON in a Struts 2.3.14 app, where we can't define a custom JsonWriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you could use 2 properties. 
`excludeNullProperties` or `includeProperties` for serializing only the desired fields. Also `includeProperties` allow the use of regular expressions in case you do not want to serialize the full object content.

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="includeProperties">
    ^entries\[\d+\].clientNumber,
    ^entries\[\d+\].scheduleNumber,
    ^entries\[\d+\].createUserId
  </param>
</result>
```

[Here](http://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/) is the official documentation.