# Struts2 (2.3.34) Rename Some Object Fields in JSON Output

Tags: json, struts2

In Struts2, I need to arbitrarily rename some fields in the JSON output coming from my `List<CustomObject>` collection.

Starting with Struts 2.5.14 there is a way to define a custom JsonWriter,
http://struts.apache.org/plugins/json/#customizing-the-output

But my app is in Struts 2.3.34.

Ex. of what I need:

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="retrieveJson" method="retrieveJson" class="myapp.MyAction">
    <result type="json">
    </result>       
</action>
```

**Return List on Server-Side**

```
public String retrieveJson() throws Exception {
    records = service.getRecords(); // This is a List<Record>
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

**Example of Record Object**

```
public class Record {
    String field1; // Getter/setters
    String field2;
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
   "records": [
       "field1" : "data 1",
       "field2" : "data 2"
   ]
}
```

Now I need to map/rename arbitrary fields: e.g. `field1 -> renamedField1`

**Desired result:**

```
{
   "records": [
       "renamedField1" : "data 1",
       "field2" : "data 2"
   ]
}
```

The Jackson annotation `@JsonProperty` had no effect:

```
@JsonProperty("renamedField1")
private String field1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use the annotation @JsonProperty("renamedField1") but you need to map the object using the jackson Object mapper in order to obtain the expected result, here you have an example how to use the jackson object mapper

```
public String retrieveJson() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(service.getRecords());
    return json;
}
```

Comment: and I can't return `json` as that's not a valid Result -- it has to be a struts.xml Result -- but thanks for the Jackson direct marshalling idea, I'm doing it into an action variable, it's working.

Comment: There are some other issues here, we can't return a "json" result in `struts.xml` because Struts will escape special chars in the string. The solution is to return a plain String Stream since Jackson has already JSON-ified it. I'll post the complete answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My final answer based on `sark2323`'s tip about directly using Jackson's `ObjectMapper`.

Server-Side

```
public class MyAction {

    private InputStream modifiedJson; // this InputStream action property
                                        // will store modified Json
    public InputStream getModifiedJson() {
        return modifiedJson;
    }
    public void setModifiedJson(InputStream modifiedJson) {
        this.modifiedJson = modifiedJson;
    }    

    // Now the handler method
    public String retrieveJson() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Publication> records = service.getRecords();

        String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(records);

        modifiedJson = new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes());
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="retrieveJson" method="retrieveJson" class="myapp.MyAction">
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/plain</param>
        <param name="inputName">modifiedJson</param>
    </result>       
</action>
```

The result is a stream (i.e. plain string) because we want to avoid Struts' internal JSON marshalling which would introduce char escaping. Jackson has already produced a JSON string and now we're just outputting it as a Plain String, via the Stream approach.